# How to mount floppy drive in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: mount, floppy

It was originally working, then I unlocked the Floppy Disk icon from the launcher.
Now I need to access the floppy and I can not figure out how to restore the floppy drive icon to the sidebar.
Is there any procedure to restore access to my floppy drive?

Comment: Mitch's answer worked for me in 12.04 LTS (thanks!)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
udisks --mount /dev/fd0
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work on a HP6530b.

Locate the floppy with:

```
sudo blkid -o list -w /dev/null
```

In the generated list you will find a column with the name `fs_type`.
In this column should be an entry with name `vfat`, that is the floppy disk.

In the device column you will see a name like

`/dev/sdc`

Thats the name of the floppy disk which you can use in:

```
udisks --mount /dev/sdc
```

Please note that there should be a disc in the floppy disk drive at all times.