# Mounting a floppy drive in Xubuntu

Tags: mount, xubuntu, floppy

I am trying to use an older computer to view some floppy disks on which I have many photos. I have installed Xubuntu 16.04. The desktop has a floppy icon and a mount option, but I get an error message. Forums say use "udisks --mount /dev/fd0", but I get the message that is not a valid command. udisks seems to be gone. Any suggestions?

Comment: udisks2 has replaced udisks.

Comment: Could you also edit your answer to include the error message? That will help with diagnosis.

Comment: Related: [This older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/168597/37165) has several answers other than udisks command, although not sure if those are still valid beyond 12.04 release.

Comment: Also, the command has changed from `udisks` (12.04) to `udisksctl` (14.04 and newer releases).