# Floppy drive not detected

Tags: floppy

I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 into which I ssh. The machine itself has a floppy disk drive but it does not show up, when I run `lsblk`. There is also no `/dev/fd0` only a `/dev/fd/0`.

Based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168597/how-do-i-use-a-floppy-drive-in-ubuntu), I

- installed `fdutils`
- added the user to the floppy group: `sudo adduser $USER floppy`
- loaded the floppy module: `sudo modprobe -v floppy`.

Doing `sudo modprobe -v floppy` did not work, I only got an error message saying `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'floppy': No such device`.

The light on the front of the floopy drive is bright green, so it at least has power.

How do I figure out if it is a hardware or software issue.

Edit:
I forgot to enable it in bios. floppy drive might still be defective (`Diskette drive 0 seek failure` sometimes on boot).

Comment: Is the floppy drive enabled in BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: thanks. it was disabled in bios. Enabled it. But now I sometimes but not always get an error `Diskette drive 0 seek failure`.

Comment: Floppy drives are not what they used to be in the 1980s; they are cheap, flimsy and unreliable. What can you expect for $15 retail? Also, if that drive was out of use for a long time in that machine, a lot of dust and grime may have accumulated inside, which makes it even less reliable.